# How to prove this result related to divisor function

Tags: number-theory, analytic-number-theory

I need help in deducing this result as a part of question in exercise.

> prove that $\sum_{d>Y}\frac{ \tau (d) }{d^2} \ll  \frac{ log Y} { Y}$.

I can write LHS  as $\sum_{d>Y}\frac{ \tau (d) }{Y^2}\ll  \frac{1}{Y^2} \sum_{d>Y}{\tau(d)}$. But I am not able to move  forward.

Comment: Your first step doesn't work since $\sum_{d > Y} \tau(d)$ diverges. Instead, you should write this as
$$\sum_{d > Y} \frac{\sum_{ab = d} 1}{d^2} = \sum_{\substack{a,b = 1 \\ ab > Y}}^{\infty} \frac{1}{a^2 b^2}.$$
Now try first bounding the sum over $a > \max\{Y/b,1\}$, then bound the ensuing sum over $b \geq 1$.

Comment: $\tau(d) \geq 1$.

Comment: @Peter  Sorry to bother you again but I  was trying to estimate $ S =\sum_{a, b =1 , ab>Y} \frac{1} {a^2 b^2} $ . let a >max { Y/b, 1} which implies a>Y/b or $\frac{ b^2} { Y^2} > \frac{1} {a^2}$  and  now S becomes $\sum_{b=1} ^{\infty} 1/Y^2 $ which again diverges. So, can you  please write a proof for that. I shall be really thankful.

Comment: Break up the sum over $b$ into $b \leq Y$ and $b > Y$. The $a$-sum will be different in each case, so you won't run into that issue. I don't know why you interchanged the order of summation after I said to bound the sum over $a$ *first* then bound the sum over $b$ *second*.

Comment: @PeterHumphries I wrote it as $\sum_{d>Y}\frac{ \tau(d)}{d^2} \leq $ $\sum_{ a =1 , \infty , b \leq Y} 1/a^2 + \sum_{a}^{\infty} 1/(aY)^2 .$. But this doesn't proves what I want to do.

Comment: It should be
$$\sum_{b \leq Y} \frac{1}{b^2} \sum_{a = 1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{a^2} + \sum_{b > Y} \frac{1}{b^2} \sum_{a > Y/b} \frac{1}{a^2}.$$
Now estimate each of these sums. I don't understand why this is so hard...